# FluentMigrator Create Clob/Text

Tags: mysql, clob, fluent-migrator

What´s the right way to create a TEXT (MYSQL) or CLOB(ORACLE/SQLSERVER) using a Migration script?

I mean something like: Alter.Column("column").OnTable("table").AsXXX

Answer (score 0):

An answer to a similar question: [Can I create a column of nvarchar(MAX) using FluentMigrator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2496695/can-i-create-a-column-of-nvarcharmax-using-fluentmigrator#answer-3175177)
The idea is to use an extension on the FluentMigrator to add a method for handling "clob like" data types. In the example solution the extension uses a `asString(int.MaxValue)` but if you intend on using each database's specific text type (example bellow extends FluentMigrator so you can use the clob type on an **alter column** migration as opposed to the linked solution which allows you to use it in a **create column**):

```
public static IAlterColumnOptionSyntax AsClob(this IAlterColumnAsTypeOrInSchemaSyntax alterColumnAsTypeOrInSchemaSyntax) {
    var currentDB = ... // get from some config
    var clobType = null;
    switch(currentDB){
        case MYSQL:
           clobType = "LONGTEXT";
        break;
        case ORACLE:
            clobType = "CLOB";
        break;
        ... // so on and so forth
    }
    return alterColumnAsTypeOrInSchemaSyntax.asCustom(clobType);
}
```

and then you can use it as:

```
Alter.Column("column").OnTable("table").AsClob();
```

not the most elegant solution because it requires you to take the migrator's driver's job and determine the text type manually but it works.